# RocksDB state backend with TableAPI

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are using TableAPI to execute few SQL queries to achieve the desired results. Whehn creating Windows out of the streams, we observed OutOfMenmory issues. We enabled RocksDB as the state backend in our manifests. How do we make sure if RocksDB is being used while using Table API. We enabled few metrics like:

```
state.backend.rocksdb.metrics.bytes-read
state.backend.rocksdb.metrics.bytes-written
state.backend.rocksdb.metrics.estimate-num-keys
```

But these metrics are not showing up when verified in the pod we deployed the Table API. They are showing for DataStream implementations. So, I wonder if the TableAPI really using RocksDB as the backend state. How can I confirm the same?

Comment: If you have configured RocksDB as a default state backend as explained on https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/state_backends/#setting-default-state-backend, the Table API will use it. This has also been explained in other Stackoverflow questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524308/state-backend-for-flink-tables